# Getting Kafka error- java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am getting the error in Kafka. While sending the message on the topic

Here is the code for sending message on topic.

```java
@Override
    public void sendMessage(User user) {
        
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Object>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(user);
        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, Object> result) {
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
            }
        });
        
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new SystemException("Error sending message to topic " + channelConfiguration.getTopic(), e);
         **Getting following error here**
        }
    }
```

Here is the error I am getting while sending message on topic

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic user_event not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture.get(SettableListenableFuture.java:119) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.test.common.messenger.kafka.sender.KafkaMessageSender.sendMessage(KafkaMessageSender.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic loyalty_event not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.lambda$buildCallback$4(KafkaTemplate.java:424) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:930) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:856) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:592) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:404) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:254) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.test.common.messenger.kafka.sender.KafkaMessageSender.sendMessage(KafkaMessageSender.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic user_event not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Does anyone knows about this?

Answer (score 0):

Topic user_event not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

Do you have the topic user_event?

If not you need to create it or else configure Kafka admin to create topic automatically.

Comment: In Spring boot it created topic automatically in kafka. So @Rohit Naik How to configure kafka to create topic automatically in embedded kafka

Comment: can you please update how you have configured Embedded  Kafka?
Via @EmbededKafka annotation or via ClassRule

Comment: The various styles of broker configuration (`@EmbeddedKafka`, `new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(...)` etc.) All provide mechanisms to create the test topic(s); just add them to the broker configuration.